# Change clicked link style

Tags: javascript, css

I have this:

```
<section class="header">
  <div class="holder">
    <span class="name">Joe Doe</span>
    <nav class="">
      <ul class="">
        <li><a href="#">Do Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Do Something Else</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Who knows</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

My script to target that and add class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header nav ul li a").click(function(e){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
)};
```

*Update* Css:

```
.header nav ul li a{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #959393;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
.active{
    color: red;
}
```

The problem:

When I click on the link, it does get the red color, but it instantly change back to the original color and the link  still with the class, maybe because the page is reloading or something ?.
I can't use `preventDefault()` because I need those links to behave as links.

Comment: It is. Just forgot to write it in here.

Comment: Why would the page reload? The URL is `#`. And it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1sztfbnw/

Comment: @j08691 I think it's reloading, I get something like a refresh. It my be my monitor though.

Comment: But you see in my fiddle the code you posted works fine right?

Comment: @j08691 I saw it now. What could it be then ? The link keeps the class, but not it's effect (the color).

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem you're having? Do you have other code that could be causing the issue that you didn't post? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: If the class is in the link, but the color is not applied, another css property must be conflicting. What happens if you do `.active{ color: red !important; }`  ?

Comment: @ThiagoPXP Then it gets red. So it's conflict? o.O I have a code that define the link color. But would that be conflicting ? Updated css

Answer (score 0):

If it gets red when you add `!important`, your problem can be fixed when you understand **css specificity**
Check the image below.

`a` is less specific. `#whatever #whatever` is more specific and wins.

[image]

Comment: Nice. I changed for `.header .active{color:red;}` and bingo. Thanks!

Comment: Thiago, is there a way to keep the active effect persistent in the other page? When You click -> get redirected -> keep the link red. Like this http://www.motogarage.com.br/

Comment: That was the solution in my other answer. (persist the class after navigation). Check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with straight-up CSS - no js/jQuery needed. Also, as long as you follow the same specificity, there's no need to append your CSS with `!important`.

```
.header nav ul li a{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #959393;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
.header nav ul li a:visited{
    color: red;
}
.header nav ul li a:active{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: visited will leave every single link that I clicked red. And I need only the active on. The proper `:active` will be red only as long as I click & hold the link.

Comment: Yes. That will happen if all the links have the same URL - which they do in the example above (all links have a hash (#) placeholder). This won't happen in a production setting once all the URLs are updated. Incidentally, that's also why you experienced what appeared to be a page refresh on click. Doing so updated the URL by appending # at the end.

Answer (score -1):

If the page is reloading, your page is losing the state and the class added by the click will be lost.

To get around that, you have to maintain the state of the page somehow.

One way would be to use `sessionStorage` and you will need ids for these links.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //reapply current active link (if found)
    if (!!sessionStorage.activeLink) {
        $("#" + sessionStorage.activeLink).addClass('active');
    }

    $(".header nav ul li a").click(function(e){
        //keep track of which link was clicked.
        sessionStorage.activeLink = $(this).prop("id");

        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
)};
```

Comment: The link still with the class, just the color is gone.